# I'm not able to test USSD php Application on dev space simulator

Tags: php, sms-gateway, ussd

Anyone there can helps me to test my USSD PHP application on Dev
Space Simulator? Because I'm not able to test my USSD application on
my local machine with Dev space Simulator that I downloaded on this
link: https://devspace.hsenidmobile.com/code/php/ussd/,

My application has two files: index.php and recall.php located in this path: C:\xampp\htdocs\ideamart

My index.php code

```
<?php 
header('Content-type:application/json'); 
$inputJson = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$input = json_decode($inputJson,TRUE); 
?>
<?php
 include 'recall.php';
 ?>
```

recall.php

```
<?php 
$data['meesage']='Dialog Idea Mart Welcome..';
$data["applicationId"] = $input["applicationId"]; 
$data["password"] = "password";
$data["version"]="1.0";
$data["sessionId"]= $input["sessionId"];
$data["ussdOperation"]="mt-cont";
$data["destinationAddress"]= $input["sourceAddress"];
$data["encoding"]="440";
$data["chargingAmount"]="5";
$json_string = json_encode($data);
$ideamartURL = "http://localhost:7000/ussd/send";

$ch = curl_init($ideamartURL); 
$options = array (
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type : application/json'); 
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string);
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$options); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
?>
```

But when I try to connect to my application through Dev_space on my
local computer through [http://localhost:10001/] (Picture 1 below for
more details), it gives me a failed message (Picture 2 below for the
fails message).

**I don't know if I miss some configuration in DEV_SPACE or in my APplicatioN or in the php.in file**

[image: USSD simulators for testing my application in my computer]

[image]

Comment: Your `$options =` array is faulty. And your code could use some indentation.

Comment: @kerbholz How can I fix it ($options)?

Comment: I indented your code, see if you can spot the errors.

Comment: Replace the `;` after `application/json');` with a `,`

Comment: Thank you @kerbholz, it working now after replacing the ; with a ,
and change the $data['meesage'] with $data['message']

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = array (
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type : application/json'); 
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string);
```

it's is the comma not semi colon here `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type : application/json');` like `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type : application/json')`

and here

```
$data['meesage']='Dialog Idea Mart Welcome..';
```

it's `$data['message']`